# Can't open "certs\ca.key" for writing, No such file or directory (openssl)

Tags: openssl, req

i have problem when Generate SSL/TLS Certificates.
i enterd this commands in windows command but i have error

```
openssl req -days 3650 -nodes -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout certs\ca.key -out certs\ca.crt -config C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
```

and error is :

```
req: Can't open "certs\ca.key" for writing, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `mkdir certs` befordhand.

Comment: tnx but its not help to me

Comment: Want to add some details?

Comment: I think it has to do with location of your certs folder. It is not in the path when you execute the openssl.